# Find beginning index and last row index of consecutive values from excel in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I have a list of excel data, and I'm trying to index the rows that the first and last consecutive numbers have, since I need the indexes for 2 other columns associated with the row. Right now I have a list index out of range. [enter image description here][1[]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dca75.png)

```
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd
import sys

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('3speedtest2.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')


count = 0
rowcount = 1
firstindex = 1
lastindex = 1
"""
for i in range(0,3):
    print("pap")
"""

while count<999999999:
    print(count)
    list=[]
    firstindex = lastindex
    list.append(firstindex)
    
    if str(worksheet.cell(rowcount,28)) == -1:
        sys.exit()
    
    if str(worksheet.cell(rowcount, 28)) == str(worksheet.cell(rowcount+1,28)):
        print (str(worksheet.cell(rowcount, 28)))
   
    else:
       print (str(worksheet.cell(rowcount, 28)))
       print ("new number")
    
       lastindex=rowcount
       list.append(lastindex)
    
    rowcount+=1
    count+=1

print (list)
```